# C++ Почему не работает предварительное объявление класса?

Tags: c++

```
//=========================================================================
class CPU;
class Memory;
class IOdevice;
class Motherboard
{
    string name;

protected:
    Memory mem;
    CPU cpu;
    IOdevice io;

public:
    Motherboard();
};

Motherboard::Motherboard()
{
    name = "Системная плата/шина данных";
    cpu = CPU();
    mem = Memory();
    io = IOdevice();
}

//=========================================================================

class CPU  : public Motherboard
{
    string name;
public:
    CPU();
};

CPU::CPU()
{
    name = "Центральный процессор";
}

//=========================================================================

class Memory  : public Motherboard
{
    string name;

    //хранящиеся данные
    string login;
    string password;
public:
    Memory();
};

Memory::Memory()
{
    name = "Память";
    login = "";
    password = "";
}

//=========================================================================

class  IOdevice : public Motherboard
{
    string name;

public:
    IOdevice();
};

IOdevice::IOdevice()
{
    name = "Устройство ввода/вывода";
}

//=========================================================================



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    return 0;

 }
```

Мне главное чтобы я мог из любого класса связаться с объектом любого другого класса (для этого я делаю наследование). Но запутался как правильно построить иерархию. Что должно идти за чем? И почему не работает предварительно объявление классов? Как решить проблему скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с тем, что такое [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Если внутри класса Вы пишете вот так

```
Memory mem;
```

то компилятору нужно знать размер класса Memory в этом месте. Если он имеет только предварительное определение, то он этого сделать не может. Поэтому, нужно либо через указатель

```
Memory *mem;
```

либо через умный указатель

```
std::unique_ptr<Memory> mem;
```

Либо расставить определения классов правильно (тогда не нужно будет предварительное определение), но это возможно только в том случае, если у Ваших классов нет циклицеских зависимостей.

Comment: Memory *mem; пробовал.
Потом когда в конструкторе выделяю под него память: mem = new Memory(); , он почемуто ругается.
Почему?

Comment: Уточняйте, как именно ругается. Но, скорее всего, в месте вызова конструктора, полное определение класса неизвестно. Нужно подключить правильный инклуд.

Comment: Я уже все переделал) Сдела все намного проще - но менее интересней.( А обратно не хочу восстанавливать. Устал я с этим с++ бороться. Что же все так сложно? Вообще не сравнить с C# или Java. Там нет столько мороки чтобы содержать переменные ссылки на объекты др классов, чтобы передавать эти ссылки, с наследованием проще... я в шоке короче))

Comment: не нужно сравнивать с++ с другими языками - это неблагодарное дело. Более того, не нужно применять идеологии с других языков - это обычно на начальном этапе только мешает.

Answer (score 0):

какой-то станный дизайн класса - почему наследуется память от материнки ? процессор от материнки ? и т.д. - как может память или процессор или устройство ввода вывода являться материнской платой ? отношение `is a` здесь не подходит вобще, вам нужно `has a`,

Тоесть я бы сперва дизайн поменял - убрал бы насследование вообще, а в классе `MotherBoard` аггрегировал бы все остальное, тоесть сделал бы память, процессор, устройство ввода вывода члены класса `MotherBoard` - а тогда думаю уже и проблем с `forward declaration` не будет

Comment: и кто тут минус поставил ?? объяснил бы хоть что не так в моих рассуждениях, если хватит смелости ??

Comment: Минус не мой, но этот ответ должен быть комментарием, т. к. не отвечает на вопрос, почему там что-то не работает. Вопросов по архитектуре в вопросе нет, так что предлагаю запостить всё это комментарием, а ответ удалить - репутации у тебя достаточно.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/177071)

Comment: @Qwertiy интересный ты человек - а это   " Но запутался как правильно построить иерархию. Что должно идти за чем?"  -   разве не про архитектуру ? человек же здесь явно хочет разобраться как построить правильный дизайн класса

Comment: Ok, убедил... Но всё равно ответ так себе...